# how to use swift 4 sorting method using #keyPath

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have an array of nsmanaged object class. And i want to sort the array using particular element.

every time i try to use it it gives me an error of **Argument of '#keyPath' refers to non-'@objc' property 'questions'** and **Cannot convert value of type 'NSSortDescriptor' to expected element type 'ServiceQuestion'**

```
[NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(objectClassArray), ascending: true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "last", ascending: true, selector:  #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
```

Use particular element instead of "last" key

```
(people as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor])
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: //        return  NSArray(array:qaArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Question.questionSequence), ascending: true, selector:  #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))]) as! [ServiceRequestQuestionAnswer]

Comment: thanks for the response, actually i an using this before but my client wants to use this new sorting method given in swift 4.  Is not there a way to use it using this keypath option.